# File-drop hover like gmail

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="drop_window">
    <input class="drop_target" type="file" class="crop locale" size="800" />
    <div class="file_name">{{ video.original_file_name }}</div>
</div>
```

To have the drop_window change color on hover, I can do:

```
.drop_window:hover {
    background: #F5FFF5;
}
```

However, if I try and drag a file into that drop_window, it does not change color. How would I make it do so, similar to Gmail's file-drop functionality?

Here is an example of what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/5MjGS/

Comment: It would be better if you could show an example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @enginefree please see jsfiddle update

Answer (score 8):

You can use just `addEventListner` on `dragenter`, And then you can adjust the style. Make sure to change the color back on `dragexit` so for example:

So if you want it just on the `div` try:

```
var drop = document.getElementById("layout");
drop.addEventListener("dragenter", change, false);
drop.addEventListener("dragleave",change_back,false);

function change() {
  drop.style.backgroundColor = '#EFF2AA';
};

function change_back() {
  drop.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
};
```

## --Edit

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zFbfE/1/

Comment: @David542 I added a jsfiddle example.

Comment: no, this only works if you drag it **outside of** the file input drop. If you drag it inside it does not work.

Comment: @David542 well google has it like I have it, they have a <div> and when the file reaches the div an event is signaled.

Comment: See my answer below. It is better to use the `dragover` event and not the `dragenter` event. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14326369/801005

Answer (score 5):

Just like @enginefree says you have to add some event to change the css styling of the upload container.

The only thing is that I should use the `dragover` event and not the `dragenter` event.

```
var drop = document.getElementById("layout");
drop.addEventListener("dragover", change, false);
drop.addEventListener("dragleave",change_back, false);
drop.addEventListener("drop", change_back, false);

function change() {
  drop.style.backgroundColor = '#EFF2AA';
};

function change_back() {
  drop.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
};
```

This is because the `dragenter` won't work if you hover over the input control or some other divs inside the upload container.
The event `dragover` wil fire if you hover over any control. You only have to remove the styling again with the `dragleave` event.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few drag and drop file upload plugins out there.

It looks like with a file, it's a hover/mouseover on the window, not necessarily on the element.

This tutorial http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/08/file-uploader/ is one I followed to impement the AJAX file upload into a site I made. Here is the demo:
http://www.inserthtml.com/demo/file-upload/

It looks like to target the enter of a dragged file they use this jQuery event handler.

```
$('#drop-files').bind('dragenter', function() {
    $(this).css({'box-shadow' : 'inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)', 'border' : '4px dashed #bb2b2b'});
    return false;
});
```

So the event handler you are looking for is dragenter.